# как перейти в другой viewcontroller в swift

Tags: swift, swift3, apple

Не могу перейти на другую страницу при нажатии на кнопку. Понятное дело, что через контрол нужно перетянуть и всё работает, но мне нужно, чтобы этa кнопка переходила на другую страницу при особом условии, а не каждый раз, когда на неё нажимают.

```
if(status == "OK") {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "EmailText");                  
    UserDefaults.standard.set(password, forKey: "PasswordText");
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
    if let data = myJson["data"] as AnyObject? {
        let id = data["id"] as! NSString?
        print (id!)
        let logo = data["logo"] as! NSString?
        print (logo!)
        let name = data["name"] as! NSString?
        print (name!)                    
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "m", sender: self)
        return;
    }
    return;
} else {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry!", message: status, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler: nil))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Если статус ок, тогда мне нужен переход, а если нет, то ничего не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```
let yourViewController = YourViewController()
present(yourViewController, animated: true)
```

Если это навигэйшн, то push

Answer (score 0):

Вот простое решение  вашей проблемы.

```swift
if (ваше условие == true) {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier"nextView") as! NextViewController
    self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Нужно было перетягивать страницу, а не кнопку, и написать диспатч:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "m", sender: self);
}
```